# Sum of residuals in constrained linear regression

Tags: constraints, regression

Does sum of residuals == 0 hold even if we add ordinality constraints for the coefficients in a regression model?

Comment: It would be great if someone can point out to any literature (paper/presentation/discussion thread) on this.

Comment: I suggest you to move your question to [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Imho, SSE can be zero if and only if your model perfectly fits the data. In the real life, this does not happen (unless your experimental data is falsified)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas the question does not appear to be about the sum of *squared* residual errors, rather the sum of residual errors without any squaring.

Comment: @Agnius Vasiliauskas  I have posted the question on stats.stackexchenge as well. Do I need to remove it from here ?

Comment: @James Phillips - Yes the question is about sum of residuals and not their squares

Comment: @JamesPhillips, Still, it's not likely for error sum to be zero - see my answer

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Please post an answer with actual regression errors.

Answer (score 0):

Errors never sum to zero in real life cases, because they have a tendency to *accumulate*.

Consider that your error uniformly fluctuates in range [-999,+999] between all data points. Now we can sum this error for `k` data points and draw a chart `err_sum = f(k)`.
C++ test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/random.h>

int main()
{

  int i,k;
  int rnd;
  int err; 
  char buf[4];

  for (k=10000; k < 1000000; k+=10000) {
    err = 0;
    for (i=0; i < k; i++) {
      getrandom(buf, 4, 0);
      rnd = *(int*)buf;
      err += rnd%1000;
    }
    std::cout << k << "," << err << "\n";
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Resulting chart is:
[image]

You can see from the graph that summed error does not converges to zero, as neither to any other value. It simply increases with more data points added. Also with each k, values are more scattered from a linear fit until to the point the behavior hardly can be called "linear".

Comment: I do not understand that these are regression errors.

Comment: Errors must have _a distribution law_, if they are distributed _uniformly_ then it doesn't matter if they are regression errors or other type of errors. My example covers uniformly distributed errors. Otherwise, you don't understand statistics too.

Comment: So you generated synthetic data that should be similar to regression errors. I understand.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, provided that regression errors are distributed uniformly. Otherwise - it may be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, errors have to distributed uniformly, i.e., errors can be both positive and negative which will cancel out to be zero. In real cases, they never equal to zero because of noise in the data. But, if you observe any pattern in the error distribution which shows steady increase or decrease, it means we haven't caught this in our model.
I am fairly new to Data Science. Kindly let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I proved that you are wrong - uniform errors will not cancel each other out to form zero error sum - see my answer. Why ? Because if, lets say previous data point made total error closer to zero, then it's more likely that next data point will make total error farther from zero again. So from point-to-point total error will fluctuate around zero with a greater amplitude- sometimes hitting zero casually and sometimes - missing it at all.